# How to load data only when a tab is clicked - I want to load data when Approvals tab is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><div id="tickets"><a href="#"  role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">My Tickets</a></div></li>
            <li class="active"><div id="approvals"><a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Approvals</a></div></li>
            <li class="active"><div id="watchlist"><a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Watchlist</a></div></li>
        </ul>
```

I have to load this when we click on my approvals tab below.
The problem is that when I load the page all the data makes the page slow. 
So I want to restrict to one tab only and then load the data on tab click.

```
                   <g:evaluate var="jvar_approvals" object="true">
                        var u = gs.getUserID();
                        var gr = new GlideRecord("sysapproval_approver");
                        gr.addQuery('approver',u);
                        gr.query();
                        gr;
                    </g:evaluate>
```

Comment: try this link http://eric.sau.pe/bootstrap-tabs-with-dynamic-content-loading/